# Can I use a browser's developer tools to see the zoom level of current map in browser?

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, zoom, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

**What I'm looking for**

Where a map is being served by Mapbox in my browser is there anywhere within the Chrome/Firefox Developer Tools where it shows the current zoom level as displayed on screen?

**What I've tried**

I can see what zoom level the map starts at (within the code for website) and could manually count the number of clicks or scrolls I make. I know there is a listener function that knows what zoom level I'm on and trying find if that is reported in the console or other part of the Developer Tools panel

**Why I'm looking for it**

I'm trying to get a feel for what data to show at what zoom level so looking a precedent websites.

Comment: If you also want to ask a question about vector tiles then please do that in a new and more specific question.  You can link to this one as background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With raster tiles you can usually see it on the tile URLs. For example the tile [https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/**16**/35270/21925.png](https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/16/35270/21925.png) corresponds to zoom level 16. This works for all XYZ tile servers. For details see [slippy map tilenames](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames).

Comment: Thanks for that, a useful answer but I'm dealing with vector tiles so have edited question to that affect.

Comment: Same applies to vector tiles, open the network tab in developer tools and pan the map to see those vector tile requests which expose the zoom in tte path.

Comment: @AndrewHarvey Thank you! Can you supply that as an answer as it's exactly what i needed, maybe clarify that the link appears as you hovver over the 'Name' column or whichever points to the png